# Redis long-polling Pub/Sub frequent message blocking

Tags: nginx, lua, redis

I'm trying to wrap my head around the Redis Pub/Sub API and setup a long-polling server.

This lua script subscribes to a 'test' channel and returns new messages received:

nginx.conf:

```
location /poll {
  lua_need_request_body on;
  default_type 'text/plain';
  content_by_lua_file '/usr/local/nginx/html/poll.lua';
}
```

poll.lua:

```
local redis = require "redis";
local red = redis:new();
local cjson = require "cjson";

red:set_timeout(30000) -- 30 sec

local resCon, err = red:connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)
if not resCon then
  ngx.print("error")
  return
end

local resSub, err = red:subscribe('r:' .. ngx.var["arg_r"]:gsub('%W',''))

if not resSub then
  ngx.print("error")
  return
end

if resSub == ngx.null then
  ngx.print("error")
  return
end

local resMsg, err = red:read_reply()

if not resMsg then
  ngx.say("0")
  return
end

ngx.say(cjson.encode(resMsg))
```

client.js:

```
var tmpR = 'test';

function poll() {
  $.get('/poll', {'r':tmpR}, function(data){
    if (data !== "error") {
      console.log(data);
      window.setTimeout(function(){
        poll();
      },1000);
    } else {
      console.log('poll fail');
    }
  })
}
```

Now, if I send `publish r:test hello` from redis-cli, I receive the message on the client and the server responds to redis-cli with `1`.  But, if I send two messages quickly, the second message doesn't broadcast and the server responds with `0`.

Are my channels only capable of receiving a message per second, or, is this a throttle on the frequency of messages a user can broadcast to a channel?

Is this the right way to approach this polling server on nginx assuming many users may be connected at one time?  Would it be more efficient to use GET requests on a timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two consecutive messages only one is going to have a subscriber listening to the result. No subscriber is listening when the second message is sent. The only subscriber is processing the previous result and returning that to the user.

Redis is **not** maintaining a message queue or similar to make sure that previously listening clients will receive the missing messages upon reconnect.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please? I just tested with 2 subscribers (Safari / Chrome on the same computer.) When I use `publish r:test hello` from the console, the server does one of things (it seems to alternate between them.)  Either it responds with `2` and I receive the message in both places, or it says `1` and it only goes to one client.  I don't quite understand why it's doing this.  Ideally, I would have x clients subscribed and then they would all receive the messages I was sending from the console.

Comment: (Is it because both clients are on the same IP and count as 1 subscriber, then when the first one gets the message it isn't delivered a second time to the same IP?  Though, why does that work sometimes?  For messages sent to a single client frequently, is a message dropped between reconnecting after the first message comes in and the second one?  It shouldn't take that long to reconnect.  Hmmm.  I don't quite understand what's going on or how this is supposed to work.)

Comment: "For messages sent to a single client frequently, is a message dropped between reconnecting after the first message comes in and the second one?" Yes, I think this is the case.

Comment: Ah, when I send a message and only receive it in one spot, it also seems to stem from the frequency.  I guess I'm just missing the messages sent between connections.  Ok, now this makes sense.  Thanks!